# ToDataURL output Webp image

Tags: javascript, konvajs, todataurl, react-konva

We currently tried out putting type as "image/webp" in konva toDataURL function.But we still get a png image.Is there a way to get webp image as output. `downloadURI( inputRefs[0].getStage().toDataURL({ pixelRatio: 1,type:"image/webp" }), "header.webp" );`

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL, only Chrome can support such output. Konva function is just proxy to native API.

Comment: Athul - can you mark my answer as correct if it was ? Or tell me why it was not acceptable pls.

Comment: Hi - if my answer was correct please could you mark it as the correct answer by clicking the tick. Marking the correct or most helpful answer helps other people judge its relevance and awards points to the answerer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Konvajs docs for stage.toDataURL()](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Stage.html#toDataURL__anchor) and toImage() both say of the mimeType:

> Can be "image/png" or "image/jpeg". "image/png" is the default

The docs can get out of date but I suspect this is probably correct.